# Vector is not clearing

Tags: c++

I have created a function that gets a series of guesses (a sequence of colors) from a user and puts them in a vector, and this function is called within a while loop in main().

Each time it is called by the while loop, the guess should be cleared before being refilled with inputs. However, within the second loop, entering a color I entered during the first loop activates my error message ("Invalid or repeated color entry..."), suggesting that the vector was not successfully cleared.

I've tried to clear it with a space, various strings, etc., but nothing seems to clear it. What am I missing?

Function:

```
void getGuess(vector<string> &currentGuessPegs, vector<string> &colorChoices, int maxPegSlots) {

string input; // stores input temporarily

// ---clear previous guess---
for (int i = 0; i < maxPegSlots; i++) {
    currentGuessPegs[i] == "";
}

// ---prompt player for each peg guess and store in currentGuessPegs---
for (int i = 0; i < maxPegSlots; i++) {
    cout << "Peg " << i+1 << ": ";
    cin >> input;

    while (find(currentGuessPegs.begin(), currentGuessPegs.end(), input) != currentGuessPegs.end() // Loops if color entry has already been used
        || find(colorChoices.begin(), colorChoices.end(), input) == colorChoices.end()) {         //  or is an invalid choice

        cout << "Invalid or repeated color entry. See color choices and re-enter a color you have not used.\n";
        cout << "Peg " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> input;
    }

    currentGuessPegs[i] = input;
}
}
```

And here is my call to the function from main():

```
// ---get and check guesses until maximum # of guesses is exceeded or solution is guessed---
while (guessCount < maximumGuesses && solutionGuessed == false) {
    getGuess(currentGuess, colorOptions, numberOfPegs); // get the guess
    solutionGuessed = checkGuess(currentGuess, solution, numberOfPegs, red, white); // check the guess; returns true if solution was guessed

    cout << "r: " << red << "   w: " << white << endl << endl;

    guessCount++;
}
```

Comment: _"I've tried to clear it with a space, various strings, etc., but nothing seems to clear it. What am I missing?"_ `currentGuess.clear()` maybe?

Comment: If I use .clear(), it deallocates the space I have allocated for my vector.

Comment: Use `push_back()` instead of sizing your vector beforehand.

Comment: Your function signature looks like badly translated C code and other things revolve around that (`std::vector` is not an array). Did you know that `std::vector` is well aware of its size and you don't need to pass another variable along with it, potentially leading to access out of bounds?

Comment: Your compiler would have pointed you right to the bug had you enabled reasonable warning levels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
currentGuessPegs[i] == "";
//                  ^^
```

Whoops.

Comment: Bah, so simple. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Human debugger signing off